# Split link to accounts list from profile page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, hidden-communities

Can we just split link to accounts list from the user profile page in case of presence hidden accounts?

> [image: hidden accounts]

I'm suggesting to add a link to [Hide Communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current) page.

Comment: @Rosie has the review yielded any conclusions?

Comment: @luuklag this isn't on the roadmap at present but may be something that will be rolled into a future update around profile pages.

Comment: For context: this was [status-review]'d in error and we removed the status tags as, in addition to what Rosie wrote above, it doesn't have enough community support for us to consider adding it to the backlog at the moment.

Comment: @JNat to be honest, I didn't understand this request at all. I assume it's something with international features I'm not familiar with, so didn't ask to clarify. Also as it appears to be well written, I didn't downvote. So maybe if it will be edited to explain better it can gather more support?